# The YouTube iframe does not work after applying COEP to the header

Tags: reactjs, next.js, iframe, youtube-api

I am using `NextJS` and added `COEP` and `COOP` to the header to use `SharedArrayBuffer`.

Below is `next.config.js`.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  swcMinify: true,
  output: 'standalone',
  images: {
    domains: [...],
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/(.*)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy',
            value: 'require-corp',
          },
          {
            key: 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy',
            value: 'same-origin',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**After setting the above, the YouTube iframe does not work.**

I am getting a url like 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/...' from a YouTube video and using it in the iframe src.

I tried applying `'Content-Security-Policy'` as shown below, but it did not work.

```
{
  key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
  value: `frame-ancestors 'self' https://www.youtube.com;`,
}
```

How do I display Youtube as an iframe?